# Unable to center two views on Storyboard with Constraints - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, constraints

I tried what I can do, but it is still not possible for me to locate two views together horizontally centered.

What I tried is as follows in the screenshot.

Could you please help me to make it work?

BR,

Erdem

[image]

Comment: How about placing them inside a UIView and centering that view horizontally?

Comment: @Michael I have already tried but no success

Answer (score 6):

Try to do this:

1. Add your ImageView and your Label inside an Horizontal Stack View
2. Set distribution and alignment to fill
3. Select the Stack and Add a Center Horizontal in Container and a Center Vertical with the View which is located the stack
4. If the imageView is too big add Height or Width Constraint to it

This probably solve your problem

Comment: I tried also putting inside an Horizontal Stack Vew, but this time the aspect ratio of the UIImageView mixes. @Guiseppe Sapienza